# Make the search engine recognize (and not ignore) symbols such as ? . , and etc

Tags: feature-request, search

I made a question, [What does the ?. mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721786), and it had almost identical duplicate ([What does question mark and dot operator ?. mean in C# 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352072)); I couldn't find it because when I first wrote my question, even when I tried to search in the search engine at the top of the page I couldn't duplicates.

All the results that showed up was `What does %Any-kind-of-operator-here% mean in C#?` and there are too much of them for me to find my question.

Shouldn't we add support for characters that are not just letters?

Pros:

1. Convenient search for (us) programmers.
2. No almost-identical duplicates, that are hard to find anyway because of the search engine.

Cons:

1. Might do problem when people search question with `?` at the end, which will give them questions with title that ends with `?` too (which is useless).
2. ??? (Help?)

Comment: Not exactly the same problem, but it's perhaps worth noting that Ruby allows method names to end with `!` or `?`, meaning `func()`, `func!()`, and `func?()` are three different functions.

Comment: @GoBusto Will it do any undesired results? If I guess right you use those for specific purposes [which will make it better], no?

Comment: Generally, functions like `gsub()` and `gsub!()` do similar things, but there could be cases where `x.default!()` *sets* `x` as the default and `x.default?()` returns a boolean to indicate whether `x` *is* the default.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This question is on the 'related' spectrum, I suggest to make it useful for any kind of character, not just specific character such as `@`.

Comment: There's also e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19870/248731, but you can't close cross-site duplicates.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yep, that more of a duplicate. I guess it popped multiple times but SO never addressed it as important. I hope mod will comment here.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky note that mods aren't responsible for implementing SE functionality.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know, but they can suggest this for the SO developers, am I wrong?

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky I don't know if their views would carry much more weight than everyone else's. The [early-2013 search engine upgrade](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) adding searching for symbols either generally or in code blocks (e.g. `[c#] code:"?." is:q` gets the question you were looking for) - it seems unlikely that an SO-specific alteration to search would be made.

Comment: Also see [Search using symbols is broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249848/search-using-symbols-is-broken) (it used to work, but not any more).

Comment: I've added a bounty to [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146546/add-code-search-syntax-to-search-tips) to get the search option for code at least visible, somewhere...

Comment: check out [stackse](http://stackse.com)