# More exact exact search

Tags: feature-request, search

How can I search for an exact phrase with non-alphanumeric characters being exact too?

I've tried to search for `"focus-within"` (a CSS pseudo-class), but the system keeps showing me pages that contain just the words "focus within" (separated by a space).

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q="focus-within"+site%3Astackoverflow.com is pretty good. The first couple of hits seem to be just from the word "focus", but the rest of them on the first page are all about the CSS pseudo-class. Throwing "css" in the search queue would probably improve the hit rate even more.

Comment: you might want to support [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290729/make-the-search-engine-recognize-and-not-ignore-symbols-such-as-and-etc?rq=1)

Comment: I agree with @Cody-Gray.

Using Google to search a specific ` site: ` is often **much better** than the site's built-in search. (Or Bing for videos.)

More google tricks here.

Comment: Btw. why Bing for videos? Is it anyhow better than searching directly in YouTube?

Comment: @Jakub-Jagiełło  - Youtube is **one of many** sites for videos.  Searching in Youtube ignores the rest.  Bing has a cool way of classifying and grouping videos from ALL sources. **For example** try [this Bing Video search](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=family+guy) for Family Guy clips.   [Honestly, it is the _ONLY_ feature I ever use in Bing.]

Comment: Wow, I've though it does not search any other sites. Do you know any special keywords for searching everything but YouTube?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No search results found for "DELETE \*" for a database-related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340469/no-search-results-found-for-delete-for-a-database-related-question)

Comment: @ashleedawg Wow it even has hover previews. That should be a thing in  video platforms.

Comment: @JakubJagiełło Just add `-site:youtube.com` to your search (note hyphen before keyword `site`). I think this works on both Bing and Google.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the little-known `code:` search operator to search only for exact code:

In your example, [Search for `code:focus-within`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3Afocus-within).

This is requested to be documented by [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331867/1739000).

Comment: True, but that doesn't find everything either. Knowing that the phrase is likely to be paired with "pseudo," you can see that [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3A"focus-within"+AND+"pseudo") yields results that the `code:` one didn't.

Answer (score 24):

Here is a [Google Advanced Search form **just** for *Stack Overflow*](https://www.google.ca/advanced_search?q=site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Aww, you all are right, using Google may be more effective than internal search.

Comment: using Google *is always* more effective than internal search ;)

Comment: @Jeutnarg that is sad, though.

Comment: @NH. google is just really good at what they're doing ;)

Comment: Google? Never heard of it.

Comment: @Chris [Here](http://bfy.tw/EjmK) you go

Comment: @ashleedawg huh... what's wrong with AltaVista?

Comment: @Chris  You're right, why mess with [the best](https://web.archive.org/web/19980210155904/http://www.altavista.com:80/)?  [LMAVTFY](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/a2/a26490d6e47e1c2ebbf9b1a23517590369a98b6432d84655f784eeaa6e9aa98b.jpg)